# Accessing vue-axios inside Vuex module actions

Tags: vue.js, vuex

In my Vuex setup, the store is currently structured like this:

```
store
 - modules
   - common_data
     - index.js
     - mutations.js 
     - actions.js 
     - getters.js
```

Now, one of the actions inside `actions.js` is defined as:

```
populateTimeZones(context) {
    var baseUrl = context.getters.getApiBaseUrl;

    this.$http.get(baseUrl + '/time-zones')
    .then(function (res){
        if(res.status == 'ok'){
            this.$store.commit('SET_TIME_ZONES', res.info.timeZones);
        } else {
            alert('An error occurred. Please try again!');
            return;
        }
    }.bind(this));
}
```

I think the Vue instance is not available here, which is causing the action to fail with the error: `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`. I've tried other combinations like `this.axios` and `vue.axios` but the result is same.

Am I doing something wrong? What is the common pattern for handling such cases?

Comment: Have you tried `import Vue from 'vue'` then `Vue.$http`. Not posted as an answer as *think* you'll need to create a view instance before `$http` will be available but I'm not in a position to test.

Comment: On a side note, I've started using something called `vue-inject` with is a DI container for Vue. It would allow you to register `axios` as a service and then simply call `VueInjector.get('axios')` whenever you need it. On the Vue component itself you can do `dependencies: ['axios']` and then use like `this.axios`. Not so much an issue in this case but helpful when you have lots of services doing work for you.

Comment: @webnoob I don't want to create a new instance because there might be some configuration on the existing instance that I'll need to access (axios interceptors, for example). I think I'll try passing in the Vue instance when my root component is loaded.

Comment: That was going to be my second suggestion.

Comment: @webnoob Wow, the injector sounds good. Will try it in future projects but things are kind of on fire right now. :D

Comment: I've posted that information as an answer along with a solution to your issue. Thought it might be useful for anyone else who pops up with a similar situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to access the Vue instance without passing it through or creating a new one.

A simple way to do what you want is to simply pass your `this` through to your action `this.$store.dispatch('populateTimeZones', this)`, then change your method signiture to `populateTimeZones({ context }, vueInstance)`. This would then allow you to access `vueInstance.$http`.

Another idea would be something called [vue-inject](https://github.com/jpex-js/vue-inject) which is a DI container for Vue. It would allow you to register axios as a service and then simply call VueInjector.get('axios') whenever you need it. On the Vue component itself you can do dependencies: ['axios'] and then use like this.axios. Not so much an issue in this case but helpful when you have lots of services doing work for you

Comment: Thanks. I was able to figure this out, but hopefully it will help someone else. :)

Comment: @dotslash Good luck with your fire ;)

Comment: hi guys I ran in same issue that got me finally here but I'm trying to edit axios header from module to put user token  and this is not affecting my main axios header and it's returning undefined when i call token from header